# Use a scalar function in case statement

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have a user defined scalar function called as fn_CountWeekDays which accepts 2 parameters startdate and enddate and returns an integer value. The function basically calculates no of weekdays between start and end date.

Function Code:

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[fn_CountWeekDays]
(
    @fromdate Datetime,
    @todate Datetime

)
RETURNS INT AS

Begin
Declare @NoOfWeekDays int
 Set @NoOfWeekDays =  (DATEDIFF(dd, @fromdate, @todate) + 1)
  -(DATEDIFF(wk, @fromdate, @todate) * 2)
  -(CASE WHEN DATENAME(dw, @fromdate) = 'Sunday' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
  -(CASE WHEN DATENAME(dw, @todate) = 'Saturday' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)

  Return @NoOfWeekDays
End
```

How to call the function in a case statement and compare it with another integer value at the same time?

Below is my query:

```
select
Case
    when Priority in ('1 - Critical','2 - High') and fn_CountWeekDays(Opened,Closed) <= 3 and ProblemState = 'Closed/Resolved' then 1 else 0
End as RCA_KPI_P1_P2_Met,
Case
    when Priority = '3 - Moderate' and fn_CountWeekDays(Opened,Closed) <= 5 and ProblemState = 'Closed/Resolved' then 1 else 0
End as RCA_KPI_P3_Met

from v_Problem
```

Comment: This doesn't work? it looks like it should

Comment: I would expect this to work as well. From a performance perspective, it would be better to rewrite the function to a table valued function

Comment: how can I used the table valued function in the case? I have updated the post to include the function code.

Answer (score 0):

Is your function an inline table valued function and not a scalar function? If so, then you may need to use it in a subquery or with `cross apply()` like so:

```
select 
    case 
    when Priority in ('1 - Critical', '2 - High')
      and w.WeekDays <= 3
      and ProblemState = 'Closed/Resolved'
      then 1
    else 0
    end as RCA_KPI_P1_P2_Met
  , case 
    when Priority = '3 - Moderate'
      and w.WeekDays <= 5
      and ProblemState = 'Closed/Resolved'
      then 1
    else 0
    end as RCA_KPI_P3_Met
from v_Problem
  cross apply tvf_CountWeekDays(Opened,Closed) w
```

If your function isn't an inline table valued function, then you should probably write one that is like so:

```
create function [dbo].[tvf_CountWeekDays] (@fromdate datetime,@todate datetime)
returns table with schemabinding as return (
  select 
      WeekDays = (datediff(day, @fromdate, @todate) + 1)
        - (datediff(week, @fromdate, @todate) * 2)
        - (case when datename(weekday, @fromdate) = 'Sunday' then 1 else 0 end)
        - (case when datename(weekday, @todate) = 'Saturday' then 1 else 0 end)
)
go
```

Reference:

- [When is a SQL function not a function? "If it’s not inline, it’s rubbish." - Rob Farley](http://blogs.lobsterpot.com.au/2011/11/08/when-is-a-sql-function-not-a-function/)
- [Inline Scalar Functions - Itzik Ben-Gan](http://sqlmag.com/sql-server/inline-scalar-functions)
- [Scalar functions, inlining, and performance: An entertaining title for a boring post - Adam Machanic](http://dataeducation.com/scalar-functions-inlining-and-performance-an-entertaining-title-for-a-boring-post/)
- [TSQL User-Defined Functions: Ten Questions You Were Too Shy To Ask - Robert Sheldon](https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/sql-training/tsql-user-defined-functions-ten-questions-you-were-too-shy-to-ask/)

Comment: my function is scalar valued. Should I use the query suggested by you?